# Find out whether number is of Power of Two

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, ecmascript-6, bitwise

**The task**

is taken from [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/power-of-two/)

> Given an integer, write a function to determine if it is a power of
>   two.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> Input: 1
>
> Output: true
>
> Explanation: 2<sup>0</sup> = 1
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> Input: 16
>
> Output: true
>
> Explanation: 2<sup>4</sup> = 16
>
> **Example 3:**
>
> Input: 218
>
> Output: false

**My solution**

```
/**
 * @param {number} n
 * @return {boolean}
 */
var isPowerOfTwo = function(n) {
  if (n <= 0 ) { return false; }
  if (n <= 2) { return true; }
  let num = n;
  do {
    const x = num / 2;
    if ((x | 0) !== x) { return false; }
    if (x === 2) { return true; }
    num = x;
  } while(num);
  return false;
};
```

Comment: The constant time solution is to `return n & (n - 1) === 0`. Try to understand how it works.

Comment: @vnp: fails for n=0.  @op: any JavaScript solution using bitwise ops on the entire input will fail for many values smaller `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (2^53 - 1) because those operations coerce inputs to 32-bit signed values.

Comment: Are you not allow to use the `Math` library?

Comment: @dwjohnston wouldn't that be too easy?

Comment: @OhMyGoodness, that's a good point, but we can use the constant-time solution as a basis for code that works with larger values (by splitting width-wise into portions, of which exactly one must be a power of two and the others exactly zero).

Answer (score 1):

I mean, I would use a library to do this. Namely, [Math.log2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log2)

```js
function isPowerOfTwo(n) {
  return Math.log2(n) % 1 === 0;
}

console.log(isPowerOfTwo(3)); //false
console.log(isPowerOfTwo(4)); //true
console.log(isPowerOfTwo(7)); //false
console.log(isPowerOfTwo(8)); //true
console.log(isPowerOfTwo(-1));//false
```

Comment: So tempting to try to resurrect the old "-1: not enough jquery" meme...

Comment: I know this is an answer from a bit ago, but the question has garnered some attention. while this might be some good advice for production code, it appears that the OP is for a challenge and being a challenge your answer would circumvent the challenge itself.

Answer (score -1):

I realize that this is an old question, but I though I'd provide my approach anyway.

What you really want to do, is count the number of active or set bits, as a power of two is always represented as a single bit.

Now, I'm not much for javascript, so this is semi pseudo/c code, but I do believe the operators are more or less the same.

```
bool isPowerOf2( uint64_t b )
{
    b = ((b >>  1) & 0x5555555555555555) + (b & 0x5555555555555555);
    b = ((b >>  2) & 0x3333333333333333) + (b & 0x3333333333333333); 
    b = ((b >>  4) & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f) + (b & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f); 
    b = ((b >>  8) & 0x00ff00ff00ff00ff) + (b & 0x00ff00ff00ff00ff); 
    b = ((b >> 16) & 0x0000ffff0000ffff) + (b & 0x0000ffff0000ffff);
    b = ((b >> 32) & 0x00000000ffffffff) + (b & 0x00000000ffffffff);
    return (b==1);
}
```

Now this is able to handle 64 bit, but if you only need 32 or less, it can be adapted accordingly.
It may look complicated, but it really isn't.
What you do is separate the bit up in to pairs and add them. First you add bit 0 with bit 1, bit 2 with bit 3, etc. Then you do the same again, adding bit 0-1 with 2-3, 4-5 with6-7, and so on.

With the exception of some architecture depended instructions, like GCCs __builin_popcount, I know of no way that is more efficient, but then again, if you're coding in javascript, that is probably not a priority, and you may want to use another method. Just know that what you really want to do, is count bits.

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].

Comment: I shall not. To me this is perfectly satisfactory.
If you, upon further review,still disagree, you may delete it, and I shall refrain from posting, anything, in the future.

Comment: Please explain how this is a *review*.  If it's not a review, it isn't "satisfactory" here.

Comment: It's a matter of definitions, and I'm not getting into a debate here, but you might want to consider how the other answers are reviews.
A problem was posed, two different solutions was suggested and I offered a third, hoping that it might help people to "learn".

Don't like it? Fine by me.

Bon voyage.

Comment: Just because the other answers are poor doesn't mean that more poor answers are welcome.